Had Paul preached to the churches of Galatia prior to his visit in Acts 14?
Assumed Backstory/Timeline. After Paul's conversion in Damascus (Acts 9:17–19), he immediately began preaching Jesus in the synagogues of Damascus (9:20), before escaping into Arabia and later returning to Damascus (Gal. 1:17). Three years later he want to Jerusalem and visited with Peter and James, the brother of Jesus (Gal. 1:19-19; Acts 9:26). Again, he was out and about preaching (Acts 9:28) but the Hellenists were plotting to kill him, so he was sent off to Tarsus (Acts 9:19–20), from whence he was then going (presumably preaching) "into the regions of Syria and Celicia" (Gal. 1:21).1 It was about a decade later before Paul would return to Jerusalem, with Barnabas and Titus (Gal. 2:1).2 Jumping ahead, sometime later Paul and Barnabas would get chartered to go on their missionary journey to Cyprus, the province of Pamphylia, and to the cities of the province of Galatia.3
The Question. These cities in lower Galatia—Iconium, Lystra, and Derbe—are not all that far from Paul's home in Tarsus. According to the nifty ORBIS trip calculator, the overland trip from Tarsus to (Syrian) Antioch would take almost 7 days (in July), while Tarsus to Iconium would take 12 days. Given that Paul was up in this region for a decade, is it reasonable to assume that Paul had preached to these churches of Galatia prior to his visit in Acts 14?
The Pertinence. What intrigues me is that the first part of the first Antioch-sanctioned missionary journey was to Cyprus (Acts 13:4–12), which was Barnabas's old stomping grounds (Acts 4:36), while the latter part of the journey was not all that far from Paul's prior base of operation in the province of Syria-Celicia. Hence, one wonders if Paul and Barnabas intended to benefit from existing relationships, as they headed out. This intent to leverage prior relationships provides insight into how they managed to get a hearing with the proconsul on Cyprus (Acts 13:7) and the ability to speak in the synagogues of Galatia (14:1). After about a decade of ministry in the general region, Paul was certainly a well-known Christian apologist for "the gospel that I proclaim among the Gentiles" (Gal. 2:2).
1 During Paul's time, the "imperial province of Syria-Celicia [was] governed by a legate with his headquarters in Syrian Antioch," and hence Paul's reference presumably refers to the political province. Ronald Y. K. Fung, The Epistle to the Galatians, New International Commentary on the New Testament (Grand Rapids, MI: Eerdmans, 1988), 80. There is a great map in Wiki.
2 I'm going with the "South Galatian hypothesis," which involves understanding Paul's reference to 14 years (Gal. 2:1) as actually being inclusive of the more than three years of activity already spoken of (e.g., Gal. 1:18). Fung, Galatians, 9.
3 Fung, Galatians, 2.

Why do you think that Luke did not include the supposed times of ministering in his very extensive account of 'The Acts of the Apostles' ? Or why would the Holy Spirit not inspire the memory, the mention and the recording of this obscure ministry ?

@NigelJ. A great question. A quick answer is that Acts was already bigger than Matthew, so needed to be selective. Some other possibilities: (1) this earlier mission in Syria-Celicia and beyond occurred before Paul was given overt sanction by the church in Jerusalem (Gal. 2:9); (2) this earlier mission didn't have the same Holy Spirit sanction as the latter trips, nor as large a team (Acts 13:2); and (3) reporting this earlier mission was not necessary for providing context for the Galatians letter.

@DanMoore I think that the best we can do is speculate on the answer. Perhaps the question could be rephrased to avoid opinion based answers?


Is it reasonable to assume that Paul had preached to these churches of Galatia prior to his visit in Acts 14?

It is both reasonable and an assumption. Acts presents what information Luke had at hand, both through written and oral accounts as well as occasional first-hand experiences such as those passages where he uses the first person plural ("we"). Unfortunately we have to speculate in order to fill in the blanks. I too find such questions intriguing. However, neither the Bible nor other sources provide us much information to allow a yes or no answer to the main question.
